# gridview editing and updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got a gridview and there is hyperlink column which says update. Upon clicking that page will redirect to another page and particular row values will display in another gridview. and there the user need to edit 1 column and make it update and after that there is a button outside gridview which is send or accept , upon clicking it a mail should get generate it should take updated grid values and send it to he other user and page should get redirected to previous page.

aspx code of gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#0061C1" 
                     BorderStyle="None" CaptionAlign="Bottom" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" 
                     Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="#0061C1" Height="70px" 
                     ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                     OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                     onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                     Width="796px">
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="LeaveID" Visible="false">
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                             VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10px" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applied By">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label 
                            ID="LoggedInUser" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                            Height="24px" Text='<%# Eval("LoggedInUser")%>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Begin Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                            ID="BeginDate" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 
                            Font-Names="Verdana" Text='<%# Eval("BeginDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' Font-Size="X-Small" Height="20px" 
                             Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                            ID="EndDate" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                            Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("EndDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>'  Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Num of Days">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                            ID="NumofDays" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                            Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("NumofDays")%>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type of Leave ">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                            ID="LeaveType" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                            Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("TypeofLeave")%>'  Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label 
                            ID="Status" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" 
                            ForeColor="Black" Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("Status")%>'  Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Reason for Reject">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="RejectReason" 
                            runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Black" 
                            Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("RejectReason")%>' Enabled="true" Visible="true" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtRejectReason" 
                            runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="X-Small" ForeColor="Black" 
                            Height="20px" Text='<%# Eval("RejectReason")%>' Enabled="true" Visible="true" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="LogdInUser" Visible="false" >
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                             VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager" Visible="false" >
                         <FooterStyle BackColor="#0061C1" />
                         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0061C1" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                             VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"  ButtonType="Button"  EditText="Edit">
                <ControlStyle Width="50" />
            </asp:CommandField>
                     </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>
```

i need to edit RejectReason Column.

cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MTMSDTO objc = new MTMSDTO();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int LeaveID = 0;
            int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["LeaveID"], out LeaveID);
            objc.LeaveID = LeaveID;
            objc.RejectReason = TxtRejectReason.Text;
            DataSet lapp = obj.GetLeaveApproved(objc);
            DataView LApp = new DataView();
            LApp.Table = lapp.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = LApp;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int LeaveID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        TextBox TxtRejectReason = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TxtRejectReason");

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

once i click edit button in gridview it shows no records

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code when gridview edit,

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gridView1= (GridView)sender;
   // Change the row state
    gridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit;

}
```

For Update(this is sample code)

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
      GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
      GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
      TextBox TxtRejectReason= (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TxtRejectReason");
      string s = TxtRejectReason.Text;
      GridView.EditIndex = -1;
      GridView.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: thnks for his... editing option is wrking nw.. but when i click on update its sayin (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index)

Comment: well im using label in item template and text box in edit item template fo editing column ..what should i use in code behind nw label or textbox

Comment: once i edit and update its saying no records found i used d code which u gave

Comment: i dont understand what is goin on... wen i insert value and click update its showin no records found can anybody sa me y it is so

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  Width = "550px"
         AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"
         Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" 
         HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"  ShowFooter = "true" 
         OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" onrowediting="EditCustomer"
         onrowupdating="UpdateCustomer"  onrowcancelingedit="CancelEdit"
         PageSize = "10" >
         <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText = "CustomerID">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerID" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID")%>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerID" Width = "40px"
        MaxLength = "5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Name">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblContactName" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("ContactName")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactName" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("ContactName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "150px"  HeaderText = "Company">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"
        Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
   </EditItemTemplate> 
   <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
        CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("CustomerID")%>'
     OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
    Text = "Delete" OnClick = "DeleteCustomer"></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add"
        OnClick = "AddNewCustomer" />
    </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" />
   </Columns>
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"  />
   </asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        BindData();
   }
}
private void BindData()
{
}
protected void AddNewCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         string CustomerID=((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCustomerID")).Text;
         string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtContactName")).Text;
         string Company = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
        //Your Code here...
 }
 protected void EditCustomer(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
       GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
 }
 protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
 {
      GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
      BindData();
  }
 protected void UpdateCustomer(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
      string CustomerID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                    .FindControl("lblCustomerID")).Text;
      string Name = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                    .FindControl("txtContactName")).Text;
      string Company = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
                    .FindControl("txtCompany")).Text;
      //Your code here...
  }

  protected void DeleteCustomer(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.CommandText = "delete from  customers where " +
       "CustomerID=@CustomerID;" +
       "select CustomerID,ContactName,CompanyName from customers";
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
    = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;
     GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
     GridView1.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments, If you like the answer click "UP"

Comment: I dint appreciate your answer, I appreciate yours kindness to the questioner :-)

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam In my Opinion the answer is perfect and correct and also working. So we community member should appreciate the answer.

Comment: im getting same error.... (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index)